# Change `prompt` value for external logins

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, google-authentication

I'd like to change the `prompt` value given to external logins when setup via ASP.NET Core.

For example with Google logins, `return Challenge()` sends the user to the google oauth page with `prompt=none`. I want to change that to `prompt=select_account`.
How would I do that?

Comment: doesn't api documents say how to do this ?

Comment: Nope. Can't find any docs on further customization.